Use column name as result of SQL query
I need to use SQL to get a XML format
Initial result



Code article
Test code
Test specification
Measure method




0211315V3
CORA_S3_CR
Contenance ras bord S3 Critique
QOI-I-005



Wanted result



Code article
Value
Column




0211315V3
CORA_S3_CR
Test code


0211315V3
Contenance ras bord S3 Critique
Test specification


0211315V3
QOI-I-005
Measure method



What can I try?

That's very few sample data. What about further article codes? What result would you expect then? Or will you always query one single article code only? Which RDBMS do you use? What have you tried?

Which database are you using?

You can use SQL's UNION ALL to unpivot the data by creating multiple rows from a single row.  This is the query:
SELECT 
    [Code article],
    [Test code] AS Value,
    'Test code' AS [Column]
FROM your_table
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    [Code article],
    [Test specification] AS Value,
    'Test specification' AS [Column]
FROM your_table
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    [Code article],
    [Measure method] AS Value,
    'Measure method' AS [Column]
FROM your_table;

Note:

SELECT Clause:

Each SELECT focuses on one column (Test code, Test specification, Measure method) and includes its associated label (Test code, Test specification, etc.) in a new column (Column).


UNION ALL:

Combines the results into a single dataset without eliminating duplicates.



Result:



Code article
Value
Column




0211315V3
CORA_S3_CR
Test code


0211315V3
Contenance ras bord S3 Critique
Test specification


0211315V3
QOI-I-005
Measure method




You need to sort the result

This is a product specific answer to a question with no dbms specified. At least let OP (and other readers) know which dbms this syntax is for.

It seems like you are trying to split the columns into rows, you can use UNPIVOT , I have added the syntax for SQL Srver.
Fiddle
select code_article, "value", "column"
from articles
unpivot (
    "value" for "column" in (Test_Code, Test_specification, Measure_method)
) as unpivoteddata;

Output


You can also use cross apply for creating multiple rows from a single row.
SELECT 
    t.[Code article], 
    v.Value, 
    v.[Column]
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES 
    (t.[Test code], 'Test code'),
    (t.[Test specification], 'Test specification'),
    (t.[Measure method], 'Measure method')
) v(Value, [Column]);


